# Regex to Find and Remove HTML ID Attribute That Starts With or Contains Specific Word

Tags: php, html, regex, wordpress, attributes

This is what I currently have:

```
<h2 id="bookmark-" class="xyz">
<h3 id="bookmark-" class="xyz">
<h4 id="bookmark-" class="xyz">
<h5 id="bookmark-" class="xyz">
<h6 id="bookmark-" class="xyz">
```

This is what the end result should be:

```
<h2 class="xyz">
<h3 class="xyz">
<h4 class="xyz">
<h5 class="xyz">
<h6 class="xyz">
```

Will this regex expression achieve what I need?

```
<id="bookmark-[^\"]*"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 1):

You should use tools like [this](https://regex101.com/) or any other regex tools that help in debugging. As I checked your regex there it will not do the job.
`[^\"]`* would match 0 or infinite characters that are not `"`. That works great. But `<` in the beginning is ruining all your efforts. So `/id="bookmark-[^\"]*/gm` will work. I also gave you my variant how I tried to solve this regex before I understood why yours isn't working.

`/id="bookmark-"/gm` This regex will match you case only if it is matches exactly `id="bookmark-"`.

`/(id="bookmark-)[\w\s]*"/gm` This regex will match will match your id and any other characters till `"`. So it will match this for example `id="bookmark-faes f1 2332454"`.

`[abc]` - Matches either an a, b or c character.
`\w` - Matches any word character `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`
`\s` - Matches any space, tab or newline character.
`*` - Matches previous character(all inside `[]` in our case) 0 or infinite times.
Flags:
`g` - global.
`m` - multi line.
Delimiters - `/`.

P.S. you probably shouldn't use regex to parse html.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to remove the ID attribute? What's the downside of parsing html with regex?

Comment: Check this out:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags
"Regular expressions are a tool that is insufficiently sophisticated to understand the constructs employed by HTML. HTML is not a regular language and hence cannot be parsed by regular expressions."
"While arbitrary HTML with only a regex is impossible, it's sometimes appropriate to use them for parsing a limited, known set of HTML. "